# Успешно установлен драйвер неизвестного устройства

Tags: windows, windows-7, драйвер

После включения компьютера получил тултип о новом устройстве, а через некоторое время увидел такое окно:

[image: Скриншот]

Как понять, что за драйвер был поставлен?

Скриншот из диспетчера устройств:

[image: Скриншот из диспетчера устройств]

PS: Windows 7 x64

Comment: хотел сказать звони в ФСБ СРОЧНО, а ты сам ФСБ. // в логах винды что говорят? В менеджере устройств тоже должно быть дофига инфы.

Comment: у меня так принтеры usb-овые глючили, HP 102x например, когда хотели пожаловаться на качество кабеля или его излишнюю длину. В этом случае ставится какой-то абстрактный usb-драйвер просто чтобы система видела что есть устройство и не ломался plug'n'play механизм.

Comment: А ты что-нибудь usb-шное местами менял? Ну из одного порта в другой перетыкал?

Comment: @strangeqargo, а по-конкретнее, что там где искать?

Comment: @donRumata, вроде нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy в менеджере устройств - unknown device и искать, а так - вот хорошая статья -  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/usbcoreblog/2009/11/03/why-is-my-usb-device-not-detected-or-comes-up-as-unknown-device/. если очень безопасности хочешь, впрочем, ребутайся с флэшки и проверяй антивирусами, вирусы любят представляться виндовыми драйверами же, поскольку в режиме ядра работают

Comment: @strangeqargo, добавил скриншот.

Comment: @Qwertiy, тогда ещё скопируй в вопрос "ID оборудования" с вкладки "Сведения".

Comment: @donRumata, `USB\UNKNOWN`. Строгое имя драйвера: `usb.inf:Generic.Section.NTamd64:BADDEVICE.Dev:6.1.7601.18328:usb\unknown`, секция inf-файла: `BADDEVICE.Dev`. Ещё то-то?

Comment: Комп - десктоп или ноутбук?

Comment: @donRumata, десктоп.

Comment: Переустановка свежих дров чипсета и дров на usb-30 с оф сайта матери вероятно поможет этим строкам пропасть. После чипсета и усб надо ребутнуться. Т.е. чипсет - перезагрузка - усб - перезагрузка.

Comment: @Qwertiy что вообще к usb подключено? Такой эффект может давать плохой контакт; недостаточный уровень питания, если устройство питается по usb; слабый выходной сигнал контроллера устройства; глюк контроллера устройства. Собственно  `usb.inf:Generic.Section.NTamd64:BADDEVICE.Dev:6.1.7601.18328:usb\unknown` говорит о том, что порт видит устройство, но устройство не предоставило информацию о себе.

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто - ищи в инете вот эти буквы и станет ясно какое устройство:

[image: все просто ищи в нете вот єти буквы и станет ясно какое устройство]

Comment: Там написано: `USB\UNKNOWN`